# A strange error occurs when running mvn test on a UNIX server

Tags: spring-boot, maven, junit

The development environment is `Unix, Java 11, Spring Boot 2.6.9, Maven 3.8.6`

I use Unix server, I try 'mvn test' command in springboot project,
the following error occurred when conducting the test related to the data source.

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------< com.example:FB_FE_020_SD_08025 >-------------------
[INFO] Building FB_FE_020_SD_08025 1.0
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:resources (default-resources) @ FB_FE_020_SD_08025 ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered properties files.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ FB_FE_020_SD_08025 ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:testResources (default-testResources) @ FB_FE_020_SD_08025 ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered properties files.
[INFO] Copying 3 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ FB_FE_020_SD_08025 ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2:test (default-test) @ FB_FE_020_SD_08025 ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 112 out of bounds for length 100
        at org.fusesource.jansi.io.AnsiOutputStream.write(AnsiOutputStream.java:196)
        at java.base/java.io.FilterOutputStream.write(FilterOutputStream.java:137)
        at java.base/java.io.PrintStream.write(PrintStream.java:559)
        at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(StreamEncoder.java:233)
        at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implWrite(StreamEncoder.java:303)
        at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implWrite(StreamEncoder.java:281)
        at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.write(StreamEncoder.java:125)
        at java.base/java.io.OutputStreamWriter.write(OutputStreamWriter.java:208)
        at java.base/java.io.BufferedWriter.flushBuffer(BufferedWriter.java:120)
        at java.base/java.io.PrintStream.write(PrintStream.java:605)
        at java.base/java.io.PrintStream.print(PrintStream.java:745)
        at java.base/java.io.PrintStream.println(PrintStream.java:882)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:414)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:347)
```

It was so weird that I didn't write anything in the test method and when I proceeded with the test, a strange error occurred

```
@Test
void test(){

}
```

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------< com.woorifis:FB_FE_020_SD_08025 >-------------------
[INFO] Building FB_FE_020_SD_08025 1.0
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:resources (default-resources) @ FB_FE_020_SD_08025 ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered properties files.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ FB_FE_020_SD_08025 ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:testResources (default-testResources) @ FB_FE_020_SD_08025 ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered properties files.
[INFO] Copying 3 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ FB_FE_020_SD_08025 ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to /app/sechul/peb-klid-project/peb-klid-project/FB_FE_020_SD_08025/target/test-classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2:test (default-test) @ FB_FE_020_SD_08025 ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1;[[[[[["
        at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
        at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:654)
        at java.base/java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:985)
        at org.fusesource.jansi.io.AnsiOutputStream.write(AnsiOutputStream.java:199)
        at java.base/java.io.FilterOutputStream.write(FilterOutputStream.java:137)
        at java.base/java.io.PrintStream.write(PrintStream.java:559)
        at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(StreamEncoder.java:233)
        at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implWrite(StreamEncoder.java:303)
        at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implWrite(StreamEncoder.java:281)
        at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.write(StreamEncoder.java:125)
        at java.base/java.io.OutputStreamWriter.write(OutputStreamWriter.java:208)
        at java.base/java.io.BufferedWriter.flushBuffer(BufferedWriter.java:120)
        at java.base/java.io.PrintStream.write(PrintStream.java:605)
        at java.base/java.io.PrintStream.print(PrintStream.java:745)
        at java.base/java.io.PrintStream.println(PrintStream.java:882)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:414)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:347)
```

I don't think it's an application problem, so what should I check?

Comment: can you add your test method if there is something in the body?

Comment: This is not your code but the module used by maven to colorize the output using ansi sequences. Do you see the same problem with a freshly downloaded and unzipped Maven?

Comment: Which version of Maven do you use? Also you are using older verisons of plugins etc. which JDK version do you use ?